# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classy_classification'

Tags: python, module

I am a beginner with python, I am working on this project using a module named classy-classification. I pip-installed it and checked if it was actually correctly installed where it should be, and tried to install it manually, but I am still getting the same ModuleNotFoundError error.

```
import spacy
import classy_classification


data = {
    "furniture": ["This text is about chairs.",
               "Couches, benches and televisions.",
               "I really need to get a new sofa."],
    "kitchen": ["There also exist things like fridges.",
                "I hope to be getting a new stove today.",
                "Do you also have some ovens."]
}

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
nlp.add_pipe(
    "text_categorizer",
    config={
        "data": data,
        "model": "spacy"
    }
)

print(nlp("I am looking for kitchen appliances.")._.cats)
```

The error:

```
C:\Users\BC\PycharmProjects\pythonai\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/BC/PycharmProjects/pythonai/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BC\PycharmProjects\pythonai\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import classy_classification
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classy_classification'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if you have multiple versions of Python installed and/or multiple environments, it can be a bit tricky to install packages. It looks like your code is running using the Python interpreter located at `C:\Users\BC\PycharmProjects\pythonai\venv\Scripts\python.exe`.

So, try using the following command to install `classy_classification`: `C:\Users\BC\PycharmProjects\pythonai\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install classy_classification`.

In general, instead of running `pip [args]`, you can run `/path/to/python -m pip [args]` to specify the Python version/interpreter that pip installs packages for.